How do I fix a PowerApps people picker combobox to search while typing or after hitting enter - currently searching is iffy
I'm new to PowerApps, have a very limited background in anything more complicated than basic HTML/CSS and Microsoft Lists. I have a Microsoft List for my job to track events - we have 30 different locations, each doing their own thing and data tracking on the results of the events is really bad right now. I put together a List for tracking, but the UI (even with JSON) just doesn't get the right look. I've put together a blank Canvas app, created various filters and galleries so everyone can find the data they need for their departments and locations and gotten every part of the form to transfer over....except the people picker for the People column. I'm using modern controls, as that's what the template set up with and have tried just about every tutorial that exists.
I had the most luck with Reza's video about creating your own people picker and used his code for the Items property as instructed:
Filter(Office365Users.SearchUserV2(
    {searchTerm: Trim(Self.SearchText),
    isSearchTermRequired: false
    }
).value, AccountEnabled = true && Not("#EXT" in UserPrincipalName)
)

But whenever I use the people picker in the app preview, I click in the box to type - an alphabetized list of all people shows up that stops about halfway through if you keep scrolling. If I start to type, the box's options don't change unless you wait about 5 seconds before typing any other key (backspaces seem to count). If I type Sam, nothing happens. If I type Sam then a space, then wait, then backspace, every Sam in the company (as well as the Samuels and Samanthas) appear. Is there any way to make the box either filter in time (i.e. if I type B, then only names that start with B appear, then as I keep typing, available options keep whittling down) OR not filter at all until the user presses the "Enter" key? Either option would work better than this type a few keys, have nothing happen, type a few keys more after waiting 5 seconds and then seeing all of the options.
I've tried dozens of tutorials, looked through various StackOverflow and Reddit threads, watched various YouTube videos - if it's on the first few pages of a search regarding "people picker searching PowerApps", I've read it and tried it to no success.
I also tried the classic combobox since so many threads say that modern controls aren't great. I couldn't get the classic combobox to do anything

I guess the filter are causing your delay and I don't relay of V2 function. Try using the normal one.
